# Disallow adding products if sku or shipping type exists in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer, shopping-cart

As the title says. I need to be able to disable adding to cart if a product sku or shipping type already exists in the cart. Any way this can be done?

Created `checkout_stop.xml` in **app/etc/modules** with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Checkout_Stop>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Checkout_Stop>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Created `config.xml` in **app/code/local/Checkout/Stop/etc** with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Checkout_Stop>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Checkout_Stop>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <checkout_stop>
            <class>checkout_stop_Model</class>
        </checkout_stop>
    </models>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <checkout_stop_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>checkout_stop_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addtocartEvent</method>
                </checkout_stop_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>

         <review_save_before>
            <observers>
                <checkout_stop_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>checkout_stop_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>autoApproveReview</method>
                </checkout_stop_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </review_save_before>
    </events>
</global>

</config>
```

Created `Observer.php` in **app/code/local/Checkout/Stop/Model** with below code

```
<?php

$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item){
    if ($item->getSku() == 'shoes1001'){
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('You cannot add that product to your cart');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: For single SKU in cart you can set maximum allowed quantity in cart to 1 from admin panel. What do you mean by shipping type.? Is it an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by observing the event: `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

So, after you've created your event observer here's what you'll do (substitute `Mycompany_Mymodule` with respective values):

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item){
    if ($item->getSku() == 'YourSKU'){
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('You cannot add that product to your cart');
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is getting the users's session quote items (cart) and comparing each item to see if their cart has the SKU I don't want. If it does I throw an exception and send a message to the customer.

Edit:

First, your module is disabled. So in the `etc/modules` file change `<active>false</active>` to `<active>true</active`.

Take a look at your `config.xml` you specify a method that your event will trigger once the event occurs. In your specific example you named the method, `addtocartEvent`. I've added this below:

```
<?php

class Checkout_Stop_Model_Observer
{
    public function addtocartEvent()
    {
        $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        foreach ($items as $item){
            if ($item->getSku() == 'shoes1001'){
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('You cannot add that product to your cart');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Any chance you can walk me through this?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I created the xml and the config.xml as well as the folders and observer. But nothing happens

Comment: Can you add your code to your original question? Just show us what you have so far

Comment: Just edited the code

Comment: Awesome. I'm going to update my answer to apply to what you have

Comment: Now I'm getting error cannot read property innerHtml of undefined

Comment: Would you be able to paste that error into here? I need to know where the error is happening

Comment: Basically happens after clicking add to cart and I get an error popup. Says exactly this. Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: That sounds to me like it's a javascript error. Is that correct?

Comment: I would try commenting out the method we added and see if that's causing the issue. Otherwise you may try just clearing the cache if you haven't already

Comment: Disabled the module and adding to cart works fine now. Error is happening in prototype.js

Comment: Is your code changing anything on the frontend? Because this is a javascript problem

Comment: It shouldn't. All I need it to do is error out if the sku shoes1001 exists in the cart already.

Comment: Try commenting out just that function and see if that's causing the issue. Don't disable the module

Comment: Which function should I comment out?

Comment: Comment out `addtocartEvent`

Comment: Did that and still error. Commented out the entire Observer and the error is gone.

Comment: Do you have `class Company_Module_Model_Observer { //Code here }` in your observer?

Comment: I forgot to add that in my example! Really sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. let me try that now

Comment: it would be this now? <?php

class checkout_stop_Model_Observer
{
    public function addtocartEvent()
    {
        $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        foreach ($items as $item){
            if ($item->getSku() == 'shoes1001'){
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('You cannot add that product to your cart');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

Comment: Same error as above

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your example. Keep in mind that capitalization is very important. So it has to be exact.

Comment: Basically, `Checkout_Stop` Should be capitalized. The first letters should always be capitalized

Comment: Should that be capitalized on every code including xml?

Comment: Just tried that. Same error

Comment: usually just the class names should be capitalized.

Comment: Would you be able to join a chatroom for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55535/discussion-between-ryan-scott-cady-and-mheredia).

Answer (score 0):

The code from your question will not work. When observing `checkout_cart_product_add_after` the **product is already added to cart/quote** and exception is thrown after that.

Since there is no `checkout_cart_product_add_before` event, you have to remove this item from cart before throwing exception.

```
class Checkout_Stop_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    public function addtocartEvent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote      = $observer->getQuote();
        $product    = $observer->getProduct();

        # new product attribute 'disallowed_sku'
        $disallowed = $product->getDisallowdSku();

        if ($disallowed) {
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($disallowed == $item->getProduct()->getSku()) {
                    $quote->removeItem($quote->getId());
                    Mage::throwException(
                        Mage::helper('sales')->__('You cannot add that product to your cart.')
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>The example uses a new product attribute, where you can set "disalowd" SKU from product edit page.</sup>

---

There are some other issues that should be fixed like in `config.xml`. Your model declaration should fit to your class names and use uppercase letters for the first letter of you class name words ... so you should change

```
<models>
    <checkout_stop>
        <class>checkout_stop_Model</class>
    </checkout_stop>
</models>
```

To

```
<models>
    <checkout_stop>
        <class>Checkout_Stop_Model</class>
    </checkout_stop>
</models>
```

Not required, but maybe you want to rewrite your observer from another extension, you should change the full class name to `[model]/observer`. *(same for `review_save_before`)*

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <checkout_stop_Model_Observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>checkout_stop_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>addtocartEvent</method>
        </checkout_stop_Model_Observer>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

To

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <some_unique_name>
            <class>checkout_stop/observer</class>
            <method>checkDisallowedProductSku</method>
        </some_unique_name>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are mistaken at the file names and inside !, update your code with:

`app/etc/modules/Checkout_Stop.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Checkout_Stop>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Checkout_Stop>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Checkout/Stop/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Checkout_Stop>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Checkout_Stop>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <checkout_stop>
                <class>Checkout_Stop_Helper</class>
            </checkout_stop>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <checkout_stop>
                <class>Checkout_Stop_Model</class>
            </checkout_stop>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <Checkout_Stop_Model_Observer_addafter>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>checkout_stop/observer</class>
                        <method>addtocartEvent</method>
                    </checkout_stop_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <review_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <Checkout_Stop_Model_Observer_savebefore>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>checkout_stop/observer</class>
                        <method>autoApproveReview</method>
                    </checkout_stop_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </review_save_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Checkout/Stop/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
class Checkout_Stop_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

`app/code/local/Checkout/Stop/Model/Observer.php`

```
class Checkout_Stop_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function addtocartEvent($observer)

    // your logic here...
}
```

Comment: The courageous who downvote, explain why ! Im waiting for your explanation ?